# Hide shareBuilder popup and post directly in Google+ in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-plus

I am using this code to share the post in Google + and its shares the post,

```
    [GPPShare sharedInstance].delegate = self;
        id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];
        [shareBuilder setPrefillText:@"Good Afternoon Friends!!!"];
        [shareBuilder setContentDeepLinkID:@"com.link.appName"];
        [shareBuilder setTitle:@"greeting" description:@"Hello Friends" thumbnailURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg"]];
 [shareBuilder open];
```

and am getting below the output like below showed

[image]

Now i need to ignore that shareBuilder and share the post directly in Google +

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to avoid the popup when posting to the Google+ stream. All posts of this sort to Google+ require the user to actively confirm the action.

If you're looking at something that doesn't require explicit user action, take a look at [app activities](https://developers.google.com/+/features/app-activities) - but these won't post directly to the stream.